# How to combine models using Mongoose Population

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

At the moment I'm defining different models in different files depending on where I use them but there are relations between them and I find myself constantly fetching one, then the other using an ID from the first. E.g.:

File 'models/users.js'

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = mongoose.connection;
var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    // fields
    companyId: {
        type: String
    }
});

var User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

module.exports.getUserById = function(id, callback){
    User.findById(id, callback);
}
```

File 'models/company.js'

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = mongoose.connection;
var CompanySchema = mongoose.Schema({
    // fields
});
// module export and functions etc.
```

So in that example the User companyId is the ID of one of the companies. Then in my routes I'll import both models, get a User, find the company ID and then fetch that company data:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var User = Promise.promisifyAll(require('../models/user'));
var Company = Promise.promisifyAll(require('../models/company'));

User.getUserByIdAsync()
.then(function(user){
    return [user, Company.getCompanyByIdAsync(user.companyId)];
}).spread(function(user,company){
    // Do stuff
}).catch(function(err)... etc });
```

I've been reading about population on the Mongoose docs here: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html but in the examples everything is in one file. I'm trying to keep models separate for maintainability (and my sanity) so any calls to other models will throw errors.

Is there a way to join the models or reference other external models so I can do this? Is the schema even right?...

I'm using Express and Mongoose.

Answer (score 0):

You can save company reference in Users Model and hence While fetching details you can get company details as well :

```
var getUserWithPopulate = function (criteria, projection, options, callback) {
  Models.Users.find(criteria, projection, options).populate([
    {path: 'company', select:'companyId, companyName'}
  ]).exec(callback);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

For reference, the fix is pretty simple. The models being in different files makes no difference.

Change the user model so that the data type is an ObjectID and the ref field references the correct model like so:

```
companyId: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Company'
}
```

And use it:

```
User.find({}).populate('companyId').exec(callback);
```

Really simple in the end..